# How to get TikTok Profile Picture from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, image, function

I was wondering if anyone knew of code to set an `HTML` image to an image on the webpage. I was thinking like fiding the `URL` with the 512 width and height and returning the link of it.

If anyone knows how to do this please help.

For example:

```
Input : reecebrutsman

Output : https://p16.muscdn.com/img/musically-maliva-obj/1652372066288645~c5_720x720.jpeg
```

Comment: The question is not that clear. Elaborate your question with proper example and share what have you been tried?

Comment: @SajeebAhamed For example, function takes a String of the users tiktok link and the method outputs the link to thier profile image

Comment: Then attach the TikTok link with your question and also tell us what exactly the output would be.

Comment: @SajeebAhamed Alright perfect, done

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".avatar-wrapper.round").style.backgroundImage
```

[Tutorial to create a scraper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0btOGPwrIY&t=1233s)

Comment: Hey thanks I saw this to work, and I was wondering how I could make it into a function, Thanks.

Comment: @ReeceBrutsman You can use node and cheerio to scrape the data off of the url and then access the url value using $(".avatar-wrapper.round").style.backgroundImage.

Comment: Here's what I've done and for some reason, it's not working. Do you know what I'm doing wrong? https://codeshare.io/5g344y

Comment: @ReeceBrutsman Be right back

Comment: Okay thank you message me when you can!

Comment: @ReeceBrutsman Seems like it is a cors problem. You will need to do exactly as the tutorial that I linked above says. You will be able to get the proper response that way.

Comment: it's not a solution in the long run. It doesn't work anymore. However you scrap the image, once Tik Tok makes changes, it will stop working.